# how to download an email attachment from gmail in python for a particular subject and date

Tags: python, python-2.7, gmail, imap, email-attachments

I am trying to download an attachment form gmail's inbox the mail comes daily and I have to download the attachment from the mail the code I have lets me download the entire attachments in my inbox. 
What I want is to download the attachment form that particular mail of that day.

I am using this code:

import email
import getpass, imaplib
import os
import sys

```
detach_dir = 'path'
# if 'attachments' not in os.listdir(detach_dir):
#     os.mkdir('attachments')

userName = 'xyz@gmail.com'
passwd = 'xyzabc'

imapSession = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
typ, accountDetails = imapSession.login(userName, passwd)
if typ != 'OK':
    print ('Not able to sign in!')
    raise


day = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
subject = 'this is the subject name'
look_for = '(SENTSINCE {0} SUBJECT "{1}")'.format(datetime.strptime(day, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%d-%b-%Y'), subject)
imapSession.select('Inbox')
typ, data = imapSession.search(None, look_for)

if typ != 'OK':
        print ('Error searching Inbox.')
        raise

     # Iterating over all emails
for msgId in data[0].split(): typ, messageParts = imapSession.fetch(msgId,'(RFC822)')
if typ != 'OK':
    print ('Error fetching mail.')
    raise

emailBody = messageParts[0][1]
mail = email.message_from_string(emailBody)
for part in mail.walk():
    if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
        # print part.as_string()
        continue
    if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
            # print part.as_string()
        continue
    fileName = part.get_filename()

    if bool(fileName):
        filePath = os.path.join(detach_dir,fileName)
        if not os.path.isfile(filePath) :
            print (fileName)
            fp = open(filePath, 'wb')
            print "done"
            fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
            fp.close()
imapSession.close()

imapSession.logout()
```

This is not downloading the file and closing plz help in resolving the code or if anybody has the code for it please give it in answer section

Comment: Your code worked fine for me once I adjusted the search time. Is there a reason you're searching SENTSINCE what's effectively datetime.now ?  FWIW, adding 'imaplib.Debug = 4' prior to creating 'imapSession' will allow you to see what's being exchanged with the server in case there's something coming back (or not coming back) that you don't expect.

Comment: I am using sentsince because I have to get the mail for today as that mail comes once per day. Can you share your piece of code for this purpose so that I can know what is the difference.

Comment: The changes I made were to hardcode the date as '01-Jan-2010' in the .format portion of your look_for...only because it was easier than sending myself a message with a certain test subject and an attachment that I could verify.

Comment: Oh...and I also precreated the path directory since that's your detach_dir.

Comment: Can you please share the code ?

Comment: Instead of:  
    look_for = '(SENTSINCE {0} SUBJECT "{1}")'.format(datetime.strptime(day, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%d-%b-%Y'), subject)  
min was:  
    look_for = '(SENTSINCE {0} SUBJECT "{1}")'.format('01-Jan-2010', subject)  
  
When you say "is not downloading the file", do you _literally_ mean the IMAP Search is not finding/returning the message you expect? How have you confirmed that?

Answer (score 0):

My external lib https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools

```
from datetime import date
from imap_tools import MailBox, AND

# get list of emails that subject contains 'the key' and date is today from INBOX
# and save its attachments to files
with MailBox('imap.mail.com').login('test@mail.com', 'pwd', 'INBOX') as mailbox:
    for msg in mailbox.fetch(AND(subject='the key', date=date.today())):
        print(msg.date, msg.subject)
        for att in msg.attachments:
            print('-', att.filename)
            with open('C:/1/{}'.format(att.filename), 'wb') as f:  # *names may repeat!
                f.write(att.payload)
```